# How to assign the value of the parms in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a ruby newbie.

I want to define a parm **user** something like:

```
@user.mail = "test@gmail.com"
@user.login = "test"
```

Then display the value in template

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

How to assign the value of **mail** and **login** to **user**?

Or what is the format, content of

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: What's @user? A model? A random identifier?

Comment: How to define user ? @NeilMiddleton

Comment: Create a class. Use an OpenStruct. Create a model. Without more information not sure how to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you use a hash ??

```
 @user = {}
 @user["mail"] = "test@mail.com"
 @user["login"] = "name"
```

you can then access these in view using

```
 <%= @user["mail"] %>
```

add this to your file if you want to use User as object(everthing is object in ruby,userdefined object is a better word)

```
class User
   attr_accessor :mail
end
```

and then you can use

```
@user = User.new
@user.mail = "test@mail"
```

u can then use this in your view

```
<%= @user.mail %>
```